# Question about $\alpha-$affine manifold of a statistical model

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, affine-geometry, information-geometry

I am reading "Methods of information geometry by shun-ichi-Amari" and I am finding it difficult to understand the following ,first let me define it,

Let $S=\{p_{\xi}/\xi\in E\}$ where $E=[\xi^1,..,\xi^n]\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be a subset of the following set
$$P(X)=\{p:X\to\mathbb{R}/p(x)>0,\int p(x)dx<\infty\}$$ where $X$ is a sample space. Let for each $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ define the following:
\begin{equation}
  L^{(\alpha)}(u) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{2}{1-\alpha}u^{\frac{1-\alpha}{2}} & :\alpha\neq1\\
      log(u) & :\alpha=1\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$l^{(\alpha)}(x;\xi)=L^{(\alpha)}(p(x;\xi))$$

if for a fixed $\alpha$ and for some coordinate system $[\theta^i]$
$$\partial_{i}\partial_{j}l^{(\alpha)}(x;\theta)=0$$ where $\partial_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta^i}$.Then we say that $S$ is $\alpha-$flat and we call such $S$ an $\alpha-$affine manifold.
This is equivalent to the existence of the functions $\{C,F_1,..,F_n\}$ on $X$ such that
$$l^{(\alpha)}(x;\theta)=C(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta^{i}F_{i}(x).$$

Example: Consider $X$ is a finite set $\{x_1,..,x_n\}$.Let $F_{i}:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $F_{i}(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$ for $i,j=1,2,...,n.$ Then for each $p\in P(X)$ using the independent parameters $\theta^1,...,\theta^n$,we have $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x))=\theta^{i}F_{i}(x)$ here $\theta^{i}=L^{(\alpha)}(p(x_i))$. Therefoe $P(X)$ is an $\alpha-$affine manifold for every $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone explain the above example,how it is defined,I am confused.All I know it that if $X$ is finite and $E=\{[\xi^1,..,\xi^n],\xi^i>0,\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi^1<1\}$

\begin{equation}
  p(x_{i},\xi) =
    \begin{cases}
      \xi^i & :1\leq i\leq n\\
      1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi^i & :i=0\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, By definition $\theta^i = L^{(\alpha)}(p(x_i))$. Now we have $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x_i)) = \theta^i \rightarrow L^{(\alpha)}(\zeta^i) = \theta^i$. If $\alpha = 1$ then $\log(\zeta^i) = \theta^i$ is the change is co-ordinate system from $\zeta$ to $\theta$. Note that the definition says the equations hold after possibly a change in co-ordinate system from $\zeta$ to $\theta$. So transformations (even non-linear) are perfectly fine as long as its a $1-1$ map between $\zeta$ and $\theta$.

The authors are trying to convey that after transforming $\{\zeta^i: i \in [n]\}$ to $\{\theta^i: i \in [n]\}$ by some 1-1 functions you should be able to write $L^{\alpha}(p(x,\zeta))$ as linear function in $\theta$. An example $f(\zeta) =e^\zeta$ becomes linear after the transformation $e^{\zeta} = \theta$. Now $f(\log(\theta)) = \theta$ (linear).Now your new function is $f(\log(.))$ and its linear.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing how we got $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x))=\theta^{i}F_{i}$

Comment: That is the defintion of new co-ordinate system $\theta^i$ which i have written as $\log(p(x_i)) = \log(\zeta^i) = \theta^i$

Comment: Yes but I am still confused about how we got that in new co-ordinate can you elaborate your answer please that will be great help,Thanks.

Comment: You are given $\zeta^i$. Now assume $\alpha = 1$ and define $\log(\zeta^i) = \theta^i$ and work out. I think in your question it should be $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x)) = \sum_i \theta^i F_i(x)$ instead of $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x)) = \theta^i F_i(x)$. If you do this then everything will follow.

Comment: The authors are trying to convery that after transforming $\{\zeta^i: i \in [n]\}$ to $\{\theta^i: i \in [n]\}$ by some 1-1 functions you should be able to write $L^{\alpha}(p(x,\zeta))$ as linear function in $\theta$. An example $f(\zeta) =e^\zeta$ becomes linear after the transformation $e^{\zeta} = \theta$. Now $f(\log(\theta)) = \theta$ (linear). Now your new function is $f(\log(.))$ and its linear.

Comment: @Andyale if u r convinced on my answer, mark it as correct answer and useful answer so that i know.

Comment: Are u convinced ? I know its a little hard to digest at first sight. The 1-1 map i told between $\zeta$ and $\theta$ is usually such that its homeomorphism (the map and its inverse are continuous)

Comment: $\theta^i = L^{(\alpha)}(p(x_i))$. Now we have $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x_i)) = \theta^i \rightarrow L^{(\alpha)}(\zeta^i) = \theta^i$. Can you explain this line , I mean we had $L^{(\alpha)}(p(x_i))=\theta^{i}$ then how this implies $L^{(\alpha)}(\xi^i)=\theta^{i}$

Comment: Since u mentioned in question $p(x_i,\zeta) = \zeta^i$, i said that. Technically the transformation is just $L^{(\alpha)}(\{p(x_i,\zeta)\}) = \{\theta^i\}$. This is a valid transformation iff this is 1-1 and this transformation and its inverse are continuous. Check the conditions on change of co-ordinates in your book.

Comment: Okay ,now I am getting it a bit . Let suppose $\alpha\neq 1$ as you said for $\alpha=1$ ,$log(\xi^i)=\theta^{i}$ for for $\alpha\neq 1$ we will have $L^{(\alpha)}(\xi^i)=\frac{2}{1-\alpha}(\xi^i)^{\frac{1-\alpha}{2}}$ and this whole thing we will take as our $\theta^{i}$ am I correct here?

Comment: yes, according to my understanding.

Comment: one more thing do you idea about the $\alpha-$ family, I need a bit of help there. You helped me lot in this problem. Thanks,Can we discuss in chat about $\alpha-$ family?

Comment: OK send me the chat link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141119/discussion-between-andyale-and-balaji-sb).